# set style in excel sheet using poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to add style to my excel file. I want to set the row/column width and row color. I am not getting the idea how can I add this.below is my code where I am writing excel file.

```
         workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        //create a new work sheet
        sheet = workbook.createSheet("Test Result");
        CellStyle style = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
        style.setWrapText(true);

        testresultdata = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object[]>();
        //add test result excel file column header
        //write the header in the first row
        testresultdata.put("1", new Object[]{"Excel First Row", 
        "Excel Second Row", "Excel 3rd Row", "Excel 4th Row"});  //This line i wrote the excel




       Set<String> keyset = testresultdata.keySet();
        int rownum = 0;
        for (String key : keyset) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
            Object[] objArr = testresultdata.get(key);

            int cellnum = 0;
            for (Object obj : objArr) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);

                if (obj instanceof Date)
                    cell.setCellValue((Date) obj);
                else if (obj instanceof Boolean)
                    cell.setCellValue((Boolean) obj);
                else if (obj instanceof String)
                    cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
                else if (obj instanceof Double)
                    cell.setCellValue((Double) obj);
            }
        }
```

Current excel view.I want to show it organized way

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are missing setting style to cell.

```
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

        int cellnum = 0;
        for (Object obj : objArr) {
            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
            cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
            if (obj instanceof Date)
                cell.setCellValue((Date) obj);
            else if (obj instanceof Boolean)
                cell.setCellValue((Boolean) obj);
            else if (obj instanceof String)
                cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
            else if (obj instanceof Double)
                cell.setCellValue((Double) obj);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but no luck.Still the view is same

Comment: Can you add other styles like background color to check style is working or not? 

cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new HSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(255, 244, 233)));
  style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

Comment: cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle); here cellStyle is giving error.Where i need to define cellStyle?